# Basic Authentication by devtools Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have problem with basic auth.
Earlier I used typical authorization by link - user:password@url, but for some reason I need to change to other way.

I want to achieve something similar to this https://medium.com/automationmaster/handling-basic-authentication-window-with-selenium-webdriver-and-devtools-api-ec716965fdb6

```
    public void setup() {
        // Setup Chrome driver
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, SECONDS);

        String username = "admin";
        String password = "admin";

        DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
        devTools.createSession();

        devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.of(100000), Optional.of(100000), Optional.of(100000)));
        String auth = username + ":" + password;

        String encodeToString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes());

        // Pass the network header -> Authorization : Basic <encoded String>
        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + encodeToString);
        devTools.send(Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders(new Headers(headers)));

        driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth");
```

but I cant convert that idea to python.

I have tried several option but none of it worked.
In my code a I have a method used to get `url` with authentication one of my ideas looks something like that:

```
    def get_url_with_authentication(self):
        username = xyz
        password = zxc

        auth = username + ":" + password

        encodeToString = base64.b64encode(auth.encode())
    encodeToString = str(encodeToString)

    return "https://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + self.__url + "/" + encodeToString
```

Answer (score 1):

As of the current state of Selenium 4, this is only possible in Java. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/bidi_api_remotewebdriver/
The better option to achieve that would be to obtain session data using requests library and then inject it into Selenium session cookie.